# Blue Prism Slow apperance of action stage

Tags: blueprism

When clicking on page or action stage I have to wait 4 seconds for the property window to open. On my friends computers it happens immedietly. This problem is in all my processes and objects. Some of my friends also have this issue on thier computers.

I have reinstall Blue Prism and SQL, then reinstall whole computer. 
It did not help.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your BP system settings page?

Comment: I hesitate to cast a close vote as it is related to software used for programming purposes, but Stack Overflow is not a Blue Prism or Windows support forum. You might be better off reaching out to Blue Prism's technical support team at support@blueprism.com and have them take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add screenshot of my BP system settings page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Int13.png)

Blue Prism's technical support team was unable to help me. 
I do not see any difference between the memory on your system and your friends system.

I have found answer on other forum.
I had to remove printer device from my computer. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the recent past we have observed performance issues with our Blue Prism Infrastructure, where the process loading from the studio was taking quite long, and even opening properties window or navigating in studio was very slow.
We did some analysis and found the below and did the cleanup which helped us.

- We found that our session log table `BPASessionLog_NonUnicode` had quite some data, millions of records, we run the house keeping script provided by Blue Prism Support Team and did the cleanup.
- We found that there were hundreds of process and object, around 2000+ object/process on the database table `BPAProcess`, which has been lying there for months, last updated months ago, we wrote a custom scripts to purge the old process and objects, which has not been updated in last 180 days.
- We disabled the option to start a runtime resource as startup from
  the setting of Blue Prism Studio.

The above steps where performed on a enterprise setup which helped improve the performance of the Blue Prism quite significantly.

Its is very important to maintain a clean database, this can been done, by executing the Housekeeping scripts provided by Blue Prism.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the "slowness" of Blueprism while interacting with it is caused by SQL server. Either the network latency si high or the server`s response is slow.

We tried to have one development environment across EMEA and APAC, but due to high network latency (~250ms) it was a cumbersome experience.